# javascript onclick and method

Tags: javascript, svg

I using SVG.JS framework for JS, and I want to add method for `onclick` event, for `selectColor` element.

```js
changeCircleColor: function() {
  this.circleColor = prompt("choose color for your circle");
},
view: function() {
  var view = SVG('viewCircle').size(300, 300).style({
    background: "black"
  });

  var circle = view.circle(280).attr({
    fill: this.circleColor,
    cx: "150",
    cy: "150"
  });
  var selectColor = view.rect(30, 30).attr({
    fill: "white",
    x: "270",
    y: "270",
    stroke: "black",
    onclick: "this.changeCircleColor()"
  })
},
```

But script can't find it.

> CircleEditor.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: this.changeCircleColor is not
>   a function
>       at SVGRectElement.onclick (CircleEditor.html:1)

Comment: Because `this` point to the window but not to the object.. If you assign this object to the `window`, for you can call it via the `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

Your issue start with the way you're passing the function handler to your SVG element.

You use a string set on the *attr()* method.

If you use a string you're very limited on what you can do. This is ok for small example or if you pass just a small piece of code, usually the whole function.

Of course the function should be isolated and self executable, without any external dependency.

But for something more, you should avoid the *attr()* and use the suggested proper method to bind events on *svg.js*:

```
element.on('click', function() {
     // your code here.
});
```

You could find the details in the documentation page: http://svgjs.dev/events/

And now about the *this* content, that is changed when the *click* event is fired, so you should pay attention about this part of your code.

The proper way to set the handler is the following:

```
element.on('click', this.changeCircleColor);
```

Not like a string but the reference to the function (actually the function body).

So you are going to assign the function of your current object as the event handler of the svg element.

If you are using the current object inside the event handler function, you should even bind the function to your object:

```
element.on('click', this.changeCircleColor.bind(this));
```

Comment: Could you explain more? I thought it is the same that my answer said.

Comment: Attribute `onClick` get string `"this.changeCircleColor()"` so you can;t bind it to nothing, event handler get an event so you can bind it to the object.

Comment: Right, it looks like this part deserve a larger explanation. I try to do it and update my answer. Thanks to point me on this. Please have a look and kindly let me know if something is wrong.

Comment: Looking better :)